# Two 24V switching power supply in one fused switch?

Tags: power-supply, power, mosfet, switching

I have two Meanwell 500w 24v 21A PSU that are going to control different heaters on a 3d printer but I don't know how to connect them in a single IEC C14 fused plug switch. They need to operate independently of each other, just turn on/off by the same switch. I have made a wiring diagram of what I have now and what I'm aiming for, just have to figure how to use the input for PSU 2.
Thanks

edit: I'm asking about connecting the fused switch (1) to the both of the PSU inputs and if its safe?
picture for reference

[![Wiring Diagram][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBWol.png[image]

Comment: If you can't put the two PSUs in parallel, you will need two independent switches connected to the same control signal, or a DPST (or DPDT) switch. In short: You can't do what you want with the equipment you have now, *unless* your PSUs are rated for parallel operation.

Comment: ..wait, are you asking about that fused switch at the bottom, or are you asking about the MOSFET switch at the left? I assumed the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect two power supplies from a single switch if it is rated to handle total power of both supplies.

> I don't know how to connect them in a single IEC C14 fused plug switch.

Wire inputs in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can wire up the two power supplies to the single switched power entry module.

[image]

Make sure to check the actual terminal assignments for your specific power entry module as the lug locations may vary from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Also note that I have shown some double crimping at the female spade lug terminals. If this is not acceptable for your application then you can get some terminals as pictured in the lower right which will convert a single spade lug on the power entry module to a pair of spade terminals.